# How to pass parameters to site/login in Yii framework

Tags: yii

In Yii framework when you call some page which is accessible for logged in users. The system automatically reidrects to the login screen as in the following example.

I requested without logging in: `localhost/mysite/index.php?r=site/showprofile`
The system redirects: `localhost/mysite/index.php?r=site/login`

What I want to do is, I want to append some parameters to the url. like

```
localhost/mysite/index.php?r=site/login&fromTv=1
```

I am sending "`fromTv=1`" to the login page but how? Rememeber that I only send this parameter on specific occacsions.

**EDIT:**
I am not directly calling site/login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first thing to do here is to know how Yii handles authorization result :

> When authorization fails, i.e., the user is not allowed to perform the
>   specified action, one of the following two scenarios may happen:
>
> - If the user is not logged in and if the [`loginUrl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#loginUrl) property of the user component is configured to be the URL of the login page, the
>     browser will be redirected to that page. Note that by default,
>     `loginUrl` points to the **`site/login`** page.
> - Otherwise an HTTP exception will be displayed with error code 403.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#handling-authorization-result

`loginUrl` can be configured in your main config, but this will not help you since you need sometimes to add a parameter in your url...

But I think you could modify your controller access rules to achieve what your are trying to do , e.g. :

```
public function accessRules()
{
    if (...)
    {
        // custom loginUrl
        Yii::app()->user->loginUrl = array('/site/login', 'fromTv'=>1);
    }

    // .....
}
```

Comment: am trying to pass parameter with the redirect function. :(

Comment: I can't understand your accessRule approach.

Comment: You just have to modify `loginUrl` before applying access rules, did you try my code ? And you should read more carefully my answer and corresponding Yii guide.

Answer (score 0):

I use CHtml

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Link Text',array('controller/action', 'param1'=>'value1')); ?>
```

You have to intercept the request :

```
class PostController extends CController
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['category']))
            $category=(int)$_GET['category'];
        else
            throw new CHttpException(404,'invalid request');

        if(isset($_GET['language']))
            $language=$_GET['language'];
        else
            $language='en';

        // ... fun code starts here ...
    }
}
```

[check here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller)

Comment: for example I request site/home, it redirects to site/login. within the site/login when I tried to trace the parameter via $_REQUEST/GET/POST it did not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CHttpRequest](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getParam-detail):

```
$isFromTv = CHttpRequest::getParam('fromTv');
```

Comment: for example I request site/home, it redirects to site/login. within the site/login when I tried to trace the parameter via $_REQUEST/GET/POST it did not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions to your question :

1) Create your own [login manager](http://www.larryullman.com/2010/07/20/forcing-login-for-all-pages-in-yii/) class that has to extend CBehavior

```
<?php
class RequireLogin extends CBehavior
{
    public function attach($owner)
    {
         $owner->attachEventHandler('onBeginRequest', array($this, 'handleBeginRequest'));
    }


    public function handleBeginRequest($event)
    {
         if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest && in_array($_GET['r'],array('site/showprofile')){
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/login', array('fromTv'=>"1")));
         }
    }

}
?>


-> add the fallowing in `protected/config/main.php`

'behaviors' => array(
       'onBeginRequest' => array(
           'class' => 'application.components.RequireLogin'
       )
    ),
```

2) You can use `function beforeAction($action)`